# selecting multiple numbers from the menu list to download and installing the software

Tags: installation, automation, input, selection, list

if (-not (Test-Path -Path "$env:ProgramData\Chocolatey\choco.exe" -PathType Leaf))
{
# from https://chocolatey.org/install

```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;
   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072;
   iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1')) 
}


# Step 2) define the array of packages you are offering

$Packages = 'googlechrome',
            'firefox',
            'codeblocks',
            'windbg',
            'nasm',
            'explorersuite',
            'pestudio',
            'vscode',
            'sysinternals',
            'python',
            'ccleaner',
            'anaconda3',
            'wireshark',
            'sublimetext3',
            'notepadplusplus',
            'Exit'



# Step 3) define the Show-Menu function

 function Show-Menu
 {
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "**********************************************"
    Write-Host "LIST OF SOFTWARES"

    # write the options using the array of packages

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Packages.Count; $i++) 
    {
        # {0,10} means right align with spaces to max 2 characters
        Write-Host ('{0,10}. {1}' -f ($i + 1), $Packages[$i])
    }

    Write-Host " q. Exit the script"
    Write-Host "*************************************************"
    Write-Host
}

# Step 4) enter an endless loop you only exit if the user enters 'q'

while ($true) 
{
    Show-Menu

    # $UserInput = Read-Host "Enter the software number to be installed"

      $UserInput = Read-Host "Select the softwares number(s) to be installed"
      $ok = $UserInput -match '[123456789101112131415]+$'

      if( -not $ok)
      {
            write-host "Invalid selection"
            sleep 2
            write-host ""
       }
       until ($ok)

       switch -Regex ($UserInput)
       {
         "1" {googlechrome}
         "2" {firefox}
         "3" {codeblocks}
         "4" {windbg}
         "5" {nasm}
         "6" {explorersuite}
         "7" {pestudio}
         "8" {vscode}
         "9" {sysinternals}
         "10" {python}
         "11" {ccleaner}
         "12" {anaconda3}
         "13" {wireshark}
         "14" {sublimetext3}
         "15" {notepadplusplus}
        

        } until ($ok)

        
    # test if the user wants to quit and if so, break the loop
   if ($UserInput -eq 'q') { break }

    # test if the user entered a number between 1 and the total number of packages (inclusive)

    if ([int]::TryParse($UserInput,[ref]$null) -and 1..$Packages.Count -contains [int]$UserInput) 
    {
        # here you install the chosen package using the array index number (= user input number minus 1)
        $packageIndex = [int]$UserInput - 1
        Write-Host "Installing $($Packages[$packageIndex])"
       # Choco install $Packages[$packageIndex] -y
         Choco install $Packages[$packageIndex] -y --ignore-checksums

    }

    else 
    {
        $availableOptions = 1..$Packages.Count -join ','
        Write-Host "Error in selection, choose $availableOptions or q" -Foreground Color Red
    }

     $null = Read-Host "Press Enter to continue"
  
}
```

I have to select multiple numbers from the menu list based on the numbers i have entered  the software's corresponding to that numbers has to be downloaded and installed. previously my script was working properly but when i add the extra code to achieve the above functionality it is not working properly. Please help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited the script sir please tell me how to select multiple numbers in the menu list so that the software's corresponding to that numbers will be installed paralley. Previously the script was working but i am entering only one number from the menu list so the software corresponding to that number is installing but now i have to enter 2 or 3 numbers so all three software's will download parally.